# How to put a text file into a string array?

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I have a short story with a couple of sentences and I have to transfer that to a string array.

Comment: Go ahead and write some code. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this article:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

specifically:

```
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Further: split the lines for storage in an array of Strings using `String[] words = line.split(" ");`